# Forcing browser mode to a html frame (internet Explorer 11)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, frame

Is it possible to create a html site where you force document mode and ie mode regardless of compatibility view being on or off?

I have IE11 and I need a simple/quick solution to an old site. The idea is to have a frame/iframe/xframe running a www.mysite.com and forcing the browser to run in IE 9.

The biggest issue is that it has to run in Internet Explorer 11, even if it is in compatibility view.

Can anyone think of something?

Thanks in advance.

Francisco

Comment: What? You can run only one mode at a time, which is defined by top window, nevertheless how many windows it contains. In IE < 9 it was possible to view (i)frame in diffrent mode from top window.

Comment: @Teemu, thanks for pointing that out. I originally thought that the document mode inheritance was inclusive to only IE9.